# sql 'AND' not giving proper result

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have an SQL table in which there is a column called country, I want to display the details where country name = UK, I am trying to do it like with the following statement:

```
select * 
from register_bs 
INNER JOIN spouse_details ON register_bs.reg = spouse_details.reg 
WHERE country != 'Australia' AND 'USA';
```

When am using only

```
country != 'Australia'
```

It's displaying UK and USA values, but when I am using the AND operator like

```
country != 'Australia' AND 'USA'
```

It's not displaying any values (I have values for UK in my table).
Can anyone please tell me why my query is not working

Comment: You have to use following predicate conditions `country != 'Australia' AND country != 'USA'`

Comment: go for `WHERE NOT IN()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is that you actually want to compare `country` to both those strings i.e.

```
country != 'Australia' AND country != 'USA'
```

or perhaps

```
country NOT IN ('Australia', 'USA')
```

The latter form is more practical when you have more than a few values.

Your code as it currently exists is trying to use `'USA'` as a boolean value, so MySQL attempts to convert it to an integer, which results in 0 (as the string has no leading digits), which then converts to false. So your condition becomes

```
 country != 'Australia' AND false
```

which is always false, hence the query returns no rows.

Answer (score 3):

This is the correct syntax :

```
select * from register_bs INNER JOIN spouse_details ON register_bs.reg
= spouse_details.reg WHERE country != 'Australia' AND country != 'USA';
```

OR for multiple values use :

```
 select * from register_bs INNER JOIN spouse_details ON register_bs.reg
 = spouse_details.reg WHERE country NOT IN('Australia', 'USA', 'DENMARK', 'JAPAN');
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a broken condition.

Use `NOT IN` operator instead.

```
select * from register_bs INNER JOIN spouse_details ON register_bs.reg = spouse_details.reg WHERE country not in ('Australia', 'USA');
```

Answer (score 1):

SQL is just like other languages; you have to repeat the country.  Try this:
    `select * from register_bs INNER JOIN spouse_details ON register_bs.reg = spouse_details.reg WHERE country != 'Australia' AND country != 'USA';`